# Trying to use a PDF417 barcode scanning SDK in my project.

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner, hybrid-mobile-app, pdf417

I am trying to create a barcode scanning hybrid mobile application that can read a PDF417 barcode. I am currently using PDF417 phonegap plugin by Microblink for the task. 
This works perfectly for scanning the barcode, but now there are new use cases in the project.

They are: 
1) We need to add proactive assistance while scanning. i.e. If the room is dark then the app should inform the user about that and suggest him to turn on the flash light. If the barcode is too far from the camera then tell the user to move the camera close to the barcode. 
2) Add a timer to the scan session, when this timer reaches 20 seconds give an error message.

I have been trying to find out whether Microblink provides support to achieve this task, but have not found any information regarding the same. 
The pricing section in the sdk website https://pdf417.mobi/ tells that the UI is customizable but I have not found anything useful thus far.

Can someone please tell me if PDF417 sdk by Microblink allow us to achieve these tasks. If not then what SDK would be appropriate for the given use cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been using Microblink scanner for a phonegap project as well and to achieve the customizations you are talking about, you would have to edit the plugin files which are native code - Objective C for iOS and Java for Android. Sorry to break it to you but without editing the native side code in the plugin, you will not be able to achieve the 1st use case.

For the second use case, call the plugin within a timeout in javascript and and quit the plugin and display the message on the response page. There is again no possibility to add an alert on the camera screen from Javascript. If you require an alert on the camera screen, you would have to do the timeout in the native side code again. Hope this helps.

Cheers!